# Detect the onscreen keyboard in Windows 10 from Winforms

Tags: winforms, windows-10, on-screen-keyboard

In a Winforms app running on Windows 10 (Anniversary or greater), is there a way to detect that the Windows onscreen keyboard has opened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can periodically enumerate all windows and search for **DirectUIHWND** class.

For the more info about windows enumeration, take a look to http://improve.dk/finding-specific-windows/

Comment: Thanks - it's a shame that there's not a cleaner way to do this!

Comment: Sean, UWP apps can detect it by using standard Windows Runtime API, but your app must be an UWP. However you need something different, for the good old fashioned WinForms. Hopefully new UI "things" sometime are using good old windows :)

Comment: Thanks, SeNS - I must get around to digging myself out of Winforms sometime! :)